# Cannot open Chrome Browser with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to tun my test script 
and I get result for

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

but nothing happens

the script:

```
import unittest
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class browser_Test(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    ### Driver setup
    chromedriver = '/Users/ohad/Documents/workspace/chromedriver'
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
    self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

def checkWebOpen(self):
    print("web opened")


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
def checkWebOpen(self):
    print("web opened")
```

to

```
def test_checkWebOpen(self):
    print("web opened")
```

for unittest to identify any method as test, it has to be started with `test_`

Comment: The main issue is that the chrome browser doesn't pop up

Comment: @OhadWaserman after this change does your first problem resolved or not ? what is the error you are getting now ?